# step to detect minutiae in fingerprint image

Tags: android, algorithm, bitmap

I have a project that need to find a new algorithm to compare fingerprint image in android device.  I have create a program that capture the image from a fingerprint scanner, and then convert it to bitmap file, the question is, how can I get the minutiae from the bitmap image? is there any algorithm to detect the image by its pixel or something so it can find the minutiae like bifurcation etc in the fingerprint image? Please help me with the step or algorithm so I can translate it to the code. Thank you very much for your help....

regards..

Comment: It sounds like you are supposed to do the research and find an algorithm, SO is not a place to outsource your tasks to.

Comment: what you mean with outsource? I'm not ask you or anyone to find the algorithm, I just want to detect the minutiae by the pixel. If anyone have do this, I think they can share the way. This is what I mean, not outsourcing my job to you. SO please think positive before answer.

Comment: "the algorithm" you seem to ask for is [a combination of](http://ai.pku.edu.cn/aiwebsite/research.files/collected%20papers%20-%20fingerprint/Minutiae%20detection%20algorithm%20for%20fingerprint%20recognition.pdf) [several algorithms](http://www.academia.edu/2537762/Fingerprint_Matching_using_Ridge-End_and_Bifurcation_Points) and you don't seem to have done enough research on that topic or your question is incredibly unclear. Either way, an answer would be [too long](http://www.amazon.com/dp/013168728X) or is currently impossible because the question is unclear.

Comment: I know that the ridge end, bifurcation can be used to compare fingerprint, and I don't ask to combine several algorithm. I just ask how to detect bifurcation or any other minutiae by it's pixel. Can we detect it with search the pixel position or something like that. I have read and study many papers with this topic, and I have read a program that compare the pixel between fingerprint image. But I don't know how to get minutiae from bitmap so I can coded it. I do have done enough research with this.

Comment: Maybe http://mycarta.wordpress.com/2011/12/14/an-example-of-forensic-image-processing-in-imagej/ can help you. You can't simply iterate over the pixels and detect something. You need several processing steps and therefore several algorithms.

Comment: Oke, thanks for your help zapl. I will check that site soon...